# Jquery custom accordion loop

Tags: jquery, accordion

Using a CMS template engine (Silverstripe) I'm looping over objects to create an according.

```
<ul class="nav nav-list">
    <% loop Faq %>
        <li id="test-$ID" class="qu">$Title</li>
        <li id="question-$ID" class="question" style="display: none">$Answer</li>
    <% end_loop %>
</ul>
```

This is pretty simple and just creates a list id with that of test-$ID and question-$ID where ID is just a number. So test-1 and question-1, test-2 question-2 etc etc

I've got some jquery that expands the question-ID with the matching test-ID is clicked.

```
<script>
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $("#test-$ID").click(function () {
            $("#test-$ID").toggleClass("active-answer");
            $("#question-$ID").slideToggle("slow");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I had this code sitting inside the loop so the value of ID is assigned but that means I'm creating possibly 100s of versions of this code with just different IDs that doesn't seem right.

How should I correctly do this? Do I want to be just loading a collection with matching key value pairs during the loop process, or should I be using partial selecting or similar on all elements and finding the matching questions and test IDs when the user clicks? Or have I completely missed the mark?

Answer (score 0):

Well I feel a bit silly. Talk about over engineering a simple problem.

```
<div class="questions">
    <% loop Faq %>
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">$Title</a></h3>

            <div>
                $Answer
            </div>
        </div>
    <% end_loop %>
</div>
```

With a small bit of code from Jquery UI library

```
<script>
    $(".questions").accordion({
        header: "> div > h3",
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        autoHeight: false,
        autoActivate: true
    });
</script>
```